# How to extract time from unix timestamp in java?

Tags: java, date, unix-timestamp

I am new to java and i am making a weather app.

I am getting data from openweathermap server in JSON format. Below is the format

```
 "sys":{  
      "type":1,
      "id":7758,
      "message":0.2194,
      "country":"India",
      "sunrise":1410569741,
      "sunset":1410614119
   },
```

I want to extract sunrise and sunset from it but what i want is only time and not date. 
Below is my code

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

            String sunrise= df.format(new Date(json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunrise")*1000).getTime());
            String sunset = df.format(new Date(json.getJSONObject("sys").getLong("sunset")*1000).getTime());
```

Problem with my code is that it is giving me both time and date and output is 
" Sep 13, 2014 6:25:41 AM" for sunrise. Similar is for sunset.
?

How shall i extract "6:25:41 AM" it? I only want time and not year/month/day

Comment: Pleas search StackOverflow before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

Or this way

```
DateFormat ddf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(ddf.format(new Date()));
```

Specify Locale it keeps you safe and Be carefull with the case of the letters for Example `H` means Hour of the day in 24-hour clock and `h` means hour of day in 12-hour clock. [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Sorry for asking this late, in format "hh:mm:ss a", what does this "a" stands for??

Comment: it stands for Am/pm marker refer the link i gave you.

Comment: thank you very much sir, it solved all my doubts.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using the correct format: [DateFormat.getTimeInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getTimeInstance%28%29).

Comment: Thank you sir, i found the answer using simpledateformat